# How to skip some loops in Ansible playbook

Tags: xml, loops, ansible, skip

I am working with Ansible and I have a playbook where I have a task like this:

```
- name: Get remote system names
  xml:
    xmlstring: "{{ item.xml }}"
    xpath: "/rpc-reply/lldp/lldp-system-name"
    content: text
  loop: "{{ topology.results }}"
  register: names
```

where:

```
"topology": {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "All items completed", 
    "results": [............] }
```

So i am looping all the results and there inside i get an item.xml from each item of the results[]. Then, I receive a specific tag. My problem is that some tags do NOT have any value for the `xpath: "/rpc-reply/lldp/lldp-system-name"` , so I would like either to skip it or just replace it with something else, because for now I get an error and my task fails so my playbook does not work fine.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Couldn’t understand clearly how do you get the tag and what does the content look like. It would be helpful if you can add those information. Also check if [when conditional](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement) be of any help. You can also assign default value using [default filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id12)

Comment: Let's say that my results are like this `"results": [
        { "item":"A", "xml": [...my rpc-reply..] },{"item":"B", "xml": [...my rpc-reply...] } ` . The problem is that `item:"A"` has a value in the specific tag from my rpc-reply , whereas B does not have any value in that xml tag. So i am getting an error while looping. @Mamun Is it more clear now ? I will also edit my question so as to make it more clear !!!

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: "xml": "<rpc-reply message-id=\"urn:uuid:f5e23f21a8a\"><lldp-neighbors-information style=\"detail\">\n</lldp-neighbors-information></rpc-reply>"}, "msg": "Xpath /rpc-reply/lldp-neighbors-information/lldp-neighbor-information/lldp-remote-system-name does not reference a node!"}
@Mamun

Comment: and i checked that the rpc-reply does not have any value for that "lldp-remote-system-name" , whereas other items from my results list do have a value which i successfully retrieve !!!

Comment: So the error is the one I guessed. If you want to skip the failed item that you mentioned on previous comment then please have a look at the way mentioned on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution but this is something you can do to skip the failed items. First collect the result of `xpath` matching to a variable and ignore error. Then loop through the collected result and use required data by skipping failed items using `when: not item.failed`.

```
- name: Get remote system names
  xml:
    xmlstring: "{{ item.xml }}"
    xpath: "/rpc-reply/lldp/lldp-system-name"
    content: text
  loop: "{{ topology.results }}"
  register: names
  ignore_errors: yes

- debug: var=item
  when: not item.failed
  with_items: "{{ names.results }}"
```

Comment: Yes it is working !!! I could not find this `ignore_errors` anywhere in the documentation !!! Thank you very much !!!!

Comment: My pleasure. [Here is the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html)